# Return Column Index for Each Matching Value in a Row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, power-automate

Excel Novice using Excel for Business (Online) here.

I am having a difficult time wrapping my head around a way to write a function that does three things for me.

1. Check a specific row of data in a large table, preferably matching ID's between the two tables (I've been using XLOOKUP to ensure that results are keyed to a specific ID)
2. Find and return the Column index for every cell within the row with the string "Yes"
3. SUM associated points tied to the column indexes.

I am creating a new QA Scoring system, and all of the questions share the potential for "Yes" and "No" but depending on the question the number of points will be different. I have been approaching this with the idea that I could return the column indexes, convert them to the points associated to the column indexes, and then SUM them for a score, but I am open to different ideas.

[Click Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H3wPCqau5H4On3wxUdETISz56ZaPXfNh/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105285056092861858213&rtpof=true&sd=true) for a Demo of what I am trying to do, included is the actual data set I was using.

Comment: If you want to do this from PowerAutomate and you want your flow to be relatively straight forward than have you looked into Office Scripts at all?

Comment: @Skin, If you mean VBA scripts, I haven't found a way to get them working in Excel Online. But I will investigate further, perhaps I missed something. 

If you mean something else, I am curious as to what I can do to get this complete.

Comment: No, not VBA, that won’t work. Literally, “Office Scripts”. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/excel

Comment: Thanks for this, I had not heard of this prior! I'm still really fresh to this, I haven't really used Excel since highschool and never for anything quite like this. I appreciate you're callout, and I'll definitely be reading up on Office Scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Points

```
=SUMIFS($O$2:$AH$2,INDEX(Raw_Data!D:W,MATCH(Scoring!A4,Raw_Data!A:A,0),0),"*")
```

Points Earned

```
=SUMIFS($O$2:$AH$2,INDEX(Raw_Data!D:W,MATCH(Scoring!A4,Raw_Data!A:A,0),0),"Yes")
```

These will work with your present setup, but in the long run it would probably be best to just add Possible Points and Points Earned columns to your Table3, if possible.

Comment: One question to confirm my understanding.
In my actual setup the table represented by Table3 is updated by a Microsoft Form; if I add a column or two to the data myself, will it update dynamically? 

If I'm being honest, I had just assumed that it wouldn't and didn't do something as simple as that in the first place.

Comment: I've never used Microsoft Forms, but I use PowerQuery in such a way every day. Get data, load to table, add columns with formulas to calculate whatever else needed, refresh connection to get new data, those extra columns are also updated.